# Anything from the Public folder is not accessible

Tags: lumen

using wamp v2.5, Lumen 5.1.x

everything was working fine a day before and then suddenly lumen is not serving any file from the public folder, giving error "No such file or directory",
for css, js, etc.

```
[Sat Sep 12 20:03:33 2015] 127.0.0.1:50530 [404]: /jquery.js - No such file or directory
```

And its not with just one project but with every other project..
Am using the 'artisan server' command to run the project.

Although the project is working correctly on another laptop !!!

Seems like some windows OS issue am running right now, so
I reinstalled WAMP, but didn't work
then I have restored an older backup image of the whole OS (partition) when things were working but still its giving the same error.

Not getting if this specific laptop/OS has problem or the project... no projects  are working... BUT they are working on another laptop...
BUT again its not working on an older image of the OS... If the current OS has issues then it should be working with an older backup image.

its getting weird.

anybody got any clue... what going on here...

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: it started to happen on the laptop also, so i suspected Git and NodeJs coz thats the only common stuff there and reinstalling NodeJs infact did solved the problem